# Produce the same result from nodejs encryption and Java encryption

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes

In NodeJS this code produces this output: 'e5bd405394d639af20d072364b57ec7c'

```
var key = 'gustavo'
var src = 'arellano'

var cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes-128-ecb", key)
var result = cipher.update(src).toString('hex');
result += cipher.final().toString('hex');
console.log(result)
```

Now, in Java, I have this method:

```
private static String encrypt(String source) throws Exception {
    byte[] input = source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest("gustavo".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc);
    
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
}
```

But, encrypt("arellano") returns "5b1AU5TWOa8g0HI2S1fsfA=="

How can I adjust the Java code for me to obtain the string that NodeJS is giving me?

Comment: Same content, different encoding: The NodeJS output is hex encoded, the Java output Base64, see [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex('Auto')To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D')&input=ZTViZDQwNTM5NGQ2MzlhZjIwZDA3MjM2NGI1N2VjN2M). Use for a hex encoding in Java e.g. [`bytesToHex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/9014097). Note that [`createCipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) is deprecated.

Comment: You can check this easily with an online decoder: https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex. Present 5b1AU5TWOa8g0HI2S1fsfA== in the first textbox, press "Convert Base64 to Hex" and receive e5bd405394d639af20d072364b57ec7c in the hex-textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Both Strings are "equivalent" for sure. I do not need to check that.
2. The question was: What do I need to change in my java code to produce the same result?.

The right answer is: Use this line of code:

```
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, cipherText));
```

Instead of:

```
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
```

That's it.

Thanks everyone for your help.